# What is the right order for 16bit data on 8bit 8080 data bus

Tags: microcontroller, c, lcd, microchip, tft

I'm trying to create a program to drive a TFT LCD with an ILI9486 in 8bit but I don't know if I must send the configuration data and commands MSB or LSB first.

The color data for the pixels in 16bits mode seems to be MSB first.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to read the portion of the data sheet pertaining to 8-bit transfers yourself to understand this.

In RGB565 mode, it could be barely argued as "big endian" in the sense that the Green bits bridge a byte boundary and the more significant ones are sent first.

In RGB666 mode each color gets and is fully contained within its own byte transfer, and since there is no relative significance between colors the question does not apply.

With the exception of "memory write" and "memory read" most registers are only 8 bits, so it does not apply to those either.  For the memory commands, you may have to figure it out for yourself, if you use those.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm more worried about the commands to configure it. As you saying all the commands are 8 bit long but, according to the command list table, the MSB are all XXXXXXXX, so they don't care but I don't know if I must to send them first or later. Are you saying that I should only send the LSB?